# Retrieving content from a web page in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, request

I am admittedly a total noob to node.js.  I am trying to do something that would seem simple but does not seem to work.  I am using the request npm module to retrieve the content from a web page.  I want to then use that content later on in the program, but it seems there is no way to return the data retrieved from the request or store it as a string in a variable since that variable would be out of scope later on in the program.

As you can see below I am making a request to a page.  The URL is just a bunch of text, but I plan to parse that into JSON data to later on be used to initialize an object.  The object initialization requires a string as its input.  But I have no idea how to use that data outside of the scope of the request of the function inside the request.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
var request = require('request');
stateString = '';


function getState() {

request('http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php', function (error, response, body) {
        stateString = body;
    });   
}

getState();
console.log(stateString);
```

Comment: You must remember that request is asynchronous and will happen after your console.log is called. Try putting your console.log underneath where you set stateString = body;

Answer (score 0):

As OwChallie mentioned in the comments, the request is sent asynchronous. In other words, the `console.log` is executed before the request has finished.

You can resolve this problem by either passing a callback to your `getState()` function or have a look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). For a basic example as this, a callback with do just fine. But once the logic in your code becomes more complicated, I highly recommend looking into Promises to make your code manageable.

Example:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = "http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/worldState.php";

function getStateUsingCallback(callback) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    callback(body);
  });
}

function getStateUsingPromise() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      return resolve(body);
    });
  })
}

// Option 1: Using a callback
getStateUsingCallback(function(body) {
   console.log(body);
});

// Option 2: Using a Promise
getStateUsingPromise()
  .then(function (body) {
    console.log(body);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Alternatively, you could force the request to be run synchronously. So the function is completely executed before running the last line. However, I  strongly recommend you start getting the hang of writing and handling asynchronous code because that is where the power of Node.js lies!